# How to create VerticalField Manager in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to know how to create `VerticalFieldManager` and i want to add some components also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of options:

A basic vertical field manager:

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
// add your fields
vfm.add(new LabelField("First Label");
vfm.add(new LabelField("Second Label");
// etc
// then don't forget to add your vertical field manager to your screen
// assuming you're in the screen's constructor:
add(vfm);
```

The labels will appear top to bottom in the order you add them.

If you're going to add more fields than will fit vertically on a screen, you may want to make your manager scrollable:

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
// the rest is the same as above
```

You can omit VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR if you don't want to see the up/down arrows.

But finally, if you just want a bunch of fields vertically on a screen, MainScreen by default uses a scrolling VerticalFieldManager as its delegate so you can just add fields directly and get the same effect:

```
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
public MyScreen() {
add(new LabelField("Label 1");
add(new LabelField("Label 2");
// etc
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creation :

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
```

Add different fields to it:

```
vfm.add(somefield);
```